# Help. Steam wont work at all on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 64-bit, steam, 15.04

I have added 32bit support and installed additional stuff through terminal.. and it still won't run..
I have AMD X4 620 and Radeon 6950 2gb.

The output of running it from the command line:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically 
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1428965940) 
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so 
libGL error: driver pointer missing 
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600 
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so 
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Answer (score 19):

So after some research, I found the solution.

Open a terminal and run these commands:

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Comment: I only had to delete libstdc++ and the folder was ~/.steam/uubntu12_32 ...
But it worked! :)
Do you have any more information on why this magic works?

Comment: Works for me :D

Comment: Thank you! This works for me (15.04, only the first line executed; the second file didn't exist). Steam opened up right away afterwards.

Comment: Didn't work for me on 15.10

Comment: In 16.04  x64 works too. But I had only libstdc++.so.6. Radeon 5770