# Unable to run steam since last update after reinstall

Tags: steam

I couldn't run steam since last update, so I reinstalled it and when I run it I get this error:

```
kunok@home:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: More (fuller) details can be found [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and run these commands:

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

More info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613532/help-steam-wont-work-at-all-on-ubuntu-15-04).